# Yield multiple values

Tags: python, generator

Can't we yield more than one value in the python generator functions?

Example,

```
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i, i+1
            
k1, k2 = gen()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 k1, k2 = a()

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

This works as follows:

```
>>> b = a()

>>> list(b)
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Same results even when I do this:

```
def a():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
        yield i+1
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Because `gen()` returns a generator (a single item - so it can't be unpacked as two), it needs to be advanced *first* to get the values...

```
g = gen()
a, b = next(g)
```

It works with `list` because that implicitly consumes the generator.

Can we further make this a generator? Something like this:

```
g = gen();
def yield_g():
    yield g.next();
    k1,k2 = yield_g();
```

and therefore `list(k1)` would give `[0,1,2,3,4]` and `list(k2)` would give `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Keep your existing generator, and use `izip` (or zip):

```
from itertools import izip
k1, k2 = izip(*gen())
```

Comment: Update: in Python 3.x, `itertools.izip` has been replaced by the built-in `zip`, so that the last code block simply becomes `k1, k2 = zip(*gen)`.

Answer (score 39):

Your function `gen` returns a generator and not values as you might expect judging from the example you gave. If you iterate over the generator the pairs of values will be yielded:

```py
    In [2]: def gen():
       ...:     for i in range(5):
       ...:         yield i, i+1
       ...:         
    
    In [3]: for k1, k2 in gen():
       ...:     print(k1, k2)
       ...:     
    0 1
    1 2
    2 3
    3 4
    4 5
```

Comment: That's not it. See Jon Clements' answer.

Comment: Well, my example is similar, in that it advances the generator using a `for`-loop. I agree that Jon's answer is more elaborative and has a better explanation of what is going wrong. I still don't understand the downvote on my answer, though.

Comment: Can we further make this a generator? Something like this 
`g = gen(); def yield_g(): yield g.next(); k1,k2 = yield_g();` and therefore `list(k1)` would give `[0,1,2,3,4]` and `list(k2)` `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: I downvoted this because it is essentially wrong. The problem is not that OP didn't use his generator in a list. The problem is that he has misunderstood what the expression `gen()` returns, and you do nothing to correct that. Indeed, you appear to share that misconception. Indeed, your first sentence is specifically incorrect - the generator `gen` is a function.

Comment: @ShyamSunder see update to my answer for example of your comment

Comment: @Marcin: I agree that gen() is a function that returns a generator (my first sentence was indeed wrong). Still, I think it is important to mention that generators are usually iterated over and a `for`-loop is the natural thing to do there. I agree that my answer could profit from some more explanation.

Comment: DavidZwicker's, answer is, in fact, the correct (and IMO best) answer to the OP's question "Can't we yield more than one value in the python generator functions?". @Marcin is confused because the OP, additionally, illustrated that he misunderstood 1) how to call a generator and 2) what his call yielded.

Answer (score 18):

### Use `yield from`

```py
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield from (i, i+1)

[v for v in gen()]
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) say:

> When `yield from <expr>` is used, it treats the supplied expression as a subiterator.

**Update**: as mentioned by [AsukaMinato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856251/yield-multiple-values/59934331?noredirect=1#comment135109338_59934331), `[v for v in gen()]` can be `list(gen())` or `[*gen()]`

Comment: From the example OP gave, I don't think `yield from` is what they're after,

Comment: @AMC , I'm sorry I didn't understand your point.

Comment: `[v for v in gen()]` can be `list(gen())` or `[*gen()]`

Answer (score 0):

**Both Solution works just fine, in case you want to return multiple values from the generator.**

```
 def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i, i+1
```

**Solution 1:**

```
 for values in gen():
     print(values[0],values[1])
```

**Solution 2:**

```
 for value1, value2 in gen():
     print(value1, value2)
```