# Unable to use different values in multiple lines while using yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I'm trying to figure out how I can print multiple values using `yield` in different lines. ***To be clearer: not using multiple `yield`; rather, one `yield` having multiple lines***. In case of `return` I can use something like this:

```
return (placeholder_one,placeholder_two,placeholder_three +
    placeholder_four,placeholder_five,placeholder_six,title,link)
```

However, I get stuck when it comes to do the same using `yield`.

My goal is to write the values in a csv file. If I use `return`, I could write the same in the following manner:

```
placeholder_one,placeholder_two,placeholder_three,placeholder_four,placeholder_five,placeholder_six,title,link = fetch_items()
writer.writerow([placeholder_one,placeholder_two,placeholder_three,placeholder_four,placeholder_five,placeholder_six,title,link])
```

If I use `yield`, i can simply use this within name function (which would be the most ideal):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in fetch_items():
        writer.writerow(item)
        print(item)
```

I've used some placeholders to make the line bigger;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = "https://stackoverflow.com"
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

def fetch_items():
    res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

    placeholder_one = "Some name"
    placeholder_two = "Some id"
    placeholder_three = "Gender info"
    placeholder_four = "Some phone"
    placeholder_five = "Some email"
    placeholder_six = "Some credit info"

    for items in soup.select(".summary"):
        title = items.select_one(".question-hyperlink").get_text(strip=True)
        link = urljoin(base,items.select_one(".question-hyperlink").get("href"))
        yield placeholder_one,placeholder_two,placeholder_three,placeholder_four,placeholder_five,placeholder_six,title,link

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in fetch_items():
        print(item)
```

How can I `yield` the values in two or three lines like the way I did with `return`?

Comment: You could have multiple `yield` statements or you could do `yield from (placeholder_one, placeholder_two, ...)`

Comment: Yep, I know it will yield a tuple.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your intention here, but I think you are wanting to yield one of the values each time - is this correct?

Comment: Check out the edit @alaniwi. It will help you understand the exact reason. Thanks.

Comment: Well if `item` is an entire row that you are trying to write to your csv file, then you would `yield` a list or tuple like you are doing originally in the question. I don't see the issue.

Comment: There is definitely an issue when the number of items supposed to be used within `yield` are around 40.

Comment: `yield` and `return` have same syntax (for your use case). If you are fine with the `return (...)` line, you can also use `yield (...)`. Long story made short: exact same lines, just changing `return` with `yield`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be just expecting something close to:

```
    for items in soup.select(".summary"):
        title = items.select_one(".question-hyperlink").get_text(strip=True)
        link = urljoin(base,items.select_one(".question-hyperlink").get("href"))
        yield (placeholder_one,placeholder_two,placeholder_three,
               placeholder_four,placeholder_five,placeholder_six,
               title,link)
```

Comment: Which is exactly what they are already doing, except that you have formatted the output tuple a bit more readably. The OP hasn't really explained why this isn't working for them, because it seems like it ought to.

Comment: @alaniwi: To be honest, I first posted that as a comment (what it should be if code in comment was readable). But after a second (well probably fourth or even more) reading I really wondered if that could be OP's question, and decided to post it as an answer. Of course if OP accepts another answer this should be deleted as Not An Answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a list or a tuple to yield:

```
yield [placeholder_one,placeholder_two,placeholder_three + placeholder_four,placeholder_five,placeholder_six,title,link]
```

As an example consider:

```
def num():
    for i in range(10):
        yield [2 + i, 6 + i, 7 + i]


for i in num():
    print(i[0])
    print(i[1])
    print(i[2])
```

Also take a look at [yield-multiple-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856251/yield-multiple-values)